# How do you sum values inside a for loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sum

I want to sum acidic as the for loop runs and then print out the total value of all the previous acidic values. My problem is right now is it is currently just printing the individual values not one summed value of acidic. How do I sum.

this is what is printing to the command window

ans =

```
5.9676
```

ans =

```
2.1676
```

here is my code

```
pki = [7.7,3.9];

t= 2;


n=55;

for i = 1:t;

    acidic = log10(1/((n-1)*(10^-pki(i))));

    sum(acidic)

end
```

Comment: As you've written this, your for-loop executes only twice.  Is this what you want?

Comment: yes. I am starting with a small number of times. I plan on importing an excel file and running it n number of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** - As [Donnie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823129/how-do-you-sum-values-inside-a-for-loop-in-matlab/1823203#1823203) points out, you don't need the `t` variable.

You don't have a semicolon on your line `sum(acidic)`, so MATLAB prints the result.  But it looks like you have some other problems - acidic is a scalar, so the value is getting overwritten each time.  Probably you want to do something like:

```
pki = [7.7,3.9];
n = 55;
acidic = log10(1./((n-1).*(10.^-pki)));

disp(sum(acidic))
```

Note the `./`, `.*`, and `.^` operators.  These tell MATLAB to do element by element operations over the vectors.  The last `disp` line tells MATLAB to print the output value.

Answer (score 6):

`sum()` is for summing all of the values in a vector, or along an axis in a matrix.  You don't need it with the way you have your code implemented.  You could just do

```
pki = [7.7,3.9];
t= 2;
n=55;
acidic = 0;
for i = 1:t;
  acidic = acidic + log10(1/((n-1)*(10^-pki(i))));
end;

acidic
```

However, that's fairly inefficent matlab.  What I would recommend doing is just calculating all of the values at once, and then use `sum`.  You don't need the `for` statement if you do it this way:

```
pki = [7.7,3.9];
t= 2;
n=55;
acidic = log10(1 ./ ((n-1) .* (10 .^ -pki)));

sum(acidic)
```

Which does the calculation in one go.  If you weren't always going to use all of pki, you could subscript into it, like so:

```
pki = [7.7,3.9];
t= 2;
n=55;
acidic = log10(1 ./ ((n-1) .* (10 .^ -pki(1:t))));

sum(acidic)
```